# Как ускорить обнаружения объекта или кода в целом?

Tags: изображения, инспекция-кода, opencv, нейронные-сети, бот

Я попытался сделать что-то типа авто-наводчика для шутера на основе yolov4.
И всё вроде бы получилось, он более-менее работает как задумано, но 3 кадра в секунду (с моими характеристиками компьютера), с учётом поворачивающейся камеры и двигающимися противниками, это слишком мало, что-бы успеть навестись, из-за чего камера просто мотается в разные стороны завидев противника.
вот код:

```
import mss
import mss.tools
import cv2 as cv
import time
import pyautogui as pg
import numpy as np

x1, x2, x3, x4 = 0, 0, 0, 0

Conf_threshold = 0.4
NMS_threshold = 0.4
COLORS = [(0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 0, 0),
          (255, 255, 0), (255, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)]

class_name = []
with open('CSv3.names', 'r') as f:
    class_name = [cname.strip() for cname in f.readlines()]

net = cv.dnn.readNet('CSv3_6000.weights', 'CSv3.cfg')
net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16)

model = cv.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416), scale=1/255, swapRB=True)


with mss.mss() as sct: 
    monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 1920, "height": 1080}
    output = "sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)
    
    starting_time = time.time()
    frame_counter = 0

    while True:

        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)

        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)

        cap = cv.imread(output)

        x1, x2, x3, x4 = 0, 0, 0, 0

        frame = cap
        frame_counter += 1
        classes, scores, boxes = model.detect(frame, Conf_threshold, NMS_threshold)
        for (classid, score, box) in zip(classes, scores, boxes):
            color = COLORS[int(classid) % len(COLORS)]
            label = "%s : %f" % (class_name[classid[0]], score)
            cv.rectangle(frame, box, color, 1)

            x1, x2, x3, x4 = box[0], box[2], box[1], box[3]

            print (box[0], box[2], box[1], box[3])


            cv.putText(frame, label, (box[0], box[1]-10),
            cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.3, color, 1)


        if x1 > 0:
            pg.moveTo(x1+x2/2, x3+x4/3)
        else:
            pass


        endingTime = time.time() - starting_time
        fps = frame_counter/endingTime

        cv.putText(frame, f'FPS: {fps}', (20, 50),
                   cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv.imshow('frame', frame)

        key = cv.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Гитхаб где можно скачать веса: https://github.com/Imandyr/Auto-aim-bot-YOLOv4-python-CS-1.6

Что можно сделать, что бы его ускорить?

UPD:
Поэксперементировав, обнаружил, что даже без самого обнаружения обьектов на кадре, лишь при его получении и отображении, скорость работы лишь чуть-чуть больше чем с обнаружением обьектов.

Comment: Пробовали профилировать?

Comment: Если честно, то нет.

Comment: Или логирование добавьте, чтобы видеть, где паузы, на что время тратится. Пробовали убирать эти надписи и т.п., может они время съедают? И можно цикл попробовать одним объектом ограничить (первым или последним), вы всё-равно наводитесь через автогуи только на последний найденный объект.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: К сожалению особых результатов не даст, при обнаружении 4 объектов в кадре, количество кадров падает всего с 3 до 2.5.

Comment: но всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я понял, что ускорить тут просто никак, так-как этот код:

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy as np


with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 1920, "height": 1080}
    output = "sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        img = sct.grab(monitor)

        mss.tools.to_png(img.rgb, img.size, output=output)
        print(output)

        img = cv2.imread(output)

        cv2.imshow("img", img)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

не содержащий никаких действий кроме делания снимка, конвертации в грб(без которой не работает детекция) и вывода, показывает практически те же результаты что и вместе со всем остальным, то-есть дело всё именно в этом, но не один из пунктов пропустить нельзя, я пытался.

Я ещё пробовал этот код из документации по mss:

```
import time

import cv2
import mss
import numpy


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        # cv2.imshow('OpenCV/Numpy grayscale',
        #            cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY))

        print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

очень быстро транслирует экран, но проблема в том, что с массивом numpy банально не удаётся провести нужных мне манипуляций (ну, или у меня просто не получается),
так-что ничего не поделать.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы советовал так попрофайлить

```
import contextlib
import time

def some_lib_func():
    time.sleep(3)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def profiler_register_time_context(func_name):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    yield
    delta = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(f"{func_name} worked {delta}s")


with profiler_register_time_context("some_lib_func"):
    some_lib_func()
```

Comment: Этот код нерабочий. Подключения библиотек не указаны, ну и в целом это не работает.

Comment: Теперь рабочий, я именл ввиду идею и то,  что автор сам напишет себе профайлер

Comment: Спасибо за способ.

Comment: @Vasily А, ну вот так работает, спасибо, мне тоже пригодится, раньше не пользовался

Comment: @fedotiK если попрофайлишь то напиши результаты, интересно же)

Comment: сделал всё что было во while True функцией, вставил её в этот профайлер, выдаёт в среднем: worked 0.43139166199999934s